# Avoiding interface duplication parsing JSON in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I have a design question regarding the cleanest way to define some interfaces/types for objects being deserialised from JSON from an API.

For example, if I had some API returning a JSON object below and a, c and d are different types but share the same property names.

```
{
  a: {
    id: "value",
    name: "value"
  },
  b: "sample",
  c: {
   id: "value",
   name: "value"
  },
  d: {
   id: "value",
   name: "value",
   other: "value"
  }
}
```

From a design point of view, I could define interfaces in several ways:

1. Simply define a single interface e.g. `IName` which contains two string properties: `id` and `name` which for the above example could be applied to `a` and `c`. Then define another interface for `d` which extends IName and adds a property for `other`.
2. Have three separate interfaces since `a`, `c` and `d` are different objects and so could have additional, different properties in future. The downside is that three interfaces would be duplicating the `id` and `name` properties.
3. Define an interface with index property e.g. `[index:string]:string` and apply this to `a`, `c` and `d`. This would remove duplication however we could have extra unwanted properties which would not be caught by compiler.

Might be a simple/silly question but thought i'd ask for opinions on this.